# convergence, is the reverse conclusion right?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I proved that if lim $a_{n}/a_{n+1}=L$ Then: lim $a_n^{1/n}=L$

But is the reverse correct? I mean if given that lim $a_n^{1/n}=L$ is it correct to conclude that:  lim $a_{n}/a_{n+1}=L$?

I couldn't find a contradict example.

Comment: Try this: 1,1,2,2,4,4,8,8,16,16...

Comment: @IvanNeretin any suggestion for a sequence with known formula like $a_{n}=n$?

Comment: @ArielCohen For $a_n=n$ both $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n/a_{n+1}=L$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=L$ are true for $L=1$. For other well-know formulas, like $a_n=2^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}$, this does not happen.

Comment: Actually it's true for =2⌊(−1)/2⌋ and L is root of 2 in both cases @Gae.S.

Comment: @ArielCohen No.

Comment: You must mean $a_{n+1}/a_n$ instead of $a_n/a_{n+1}$ in both parts; otherwise $a_n=2^n$ is a counterexample to both.